# WPF Popup follow mouse in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I'm fighting with making popup follow mouse within DataTemplate

I have following DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyPanel">
        <Popup x:Name="MyPopup"  Visibility="Visible" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="MousePoint">
            something here
        </Popup>
        <controls1:ImageLoader x:Name="MyImage" Margin="10,10,0,0" Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Width="100" Height="100">
        </controls1:ImageLoader>
    </StackPanel>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MyImage.MouseEnter" >
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
                        Duration="0:0:0.5">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="100%"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MyPanel.MouseLeave" >
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
                        Duration="0:0:0.01">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="100%"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Right now popup is working : I mean it shows after 500ms and hides (almost correctly)

I'm trying to make a popup follows my mouse pointer while moving around `MyImage` control.

How to do it?

Comment: If it were me, I'd just style a ToolTip template to look the same as the pop-up you're after and let the ToolTipService do all the work.